# convert a uint8 array ( javascript new Uint8Array() ) to binary format (or binary mode ?) in shell / bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, array

The question is about convert from `new Uint8Array()` generated from javascript into a normal file (file that can be used with other programs like ffmpeg)

** I don't know the right term to use if it's uint8 to binary or some other term...

In javascript I have a fileReader buffer converted to uint8 to be sent via ajax...

what is sent is an array like this `23,42,69,333,99` ...

In PHP I can invoke `fopen(pack("C*", ...$uintARRAY),"wb")` "wb" for Write and Binary mode....

the end result is a file with this kind of "binary" stuff :

`Eﬂ££BÜÅB˜ÅBÚÅBÛÅBÇàmatroskaBáÅBÖÅSÄgˇˇˇˇˇˇˇI©fô*◊±ÉB@MÄÜChrome`

in linux bash script or shell command, what is the equivelent of `pack("C*", ...$uintARRAY)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do something like:

```
values=(1 2 255)
perl -e 'print pack "C*", @ARGV' -- "${values[@]}"
```

(or the equivalent with `php -r`).

To print the bytes with those values.

Beware most systems have a limit on the number and size of arguments passed to a command.

If switching to `zsh` is an option, you could do:

```
set +o multibyte
printf %s ${(#)values}
```

As `printf` is builtin, it's no affected by that limit above.

With `bash`+`perl` to work around the `execve()` limit on the number of arguments, you could feed the list of numbers via stdin instead of arguments:

```
(( ${#values[@]} )) && printf '%s\n' "${values[@]}" |
  perl -ne 'printf "%c", $_'
```

Both `perl` and `zsh` will accept numbers such as 1, 2.55e2, 0xff. For both, 0177 is interpreted as decimal, not octal, though in zsh that can be changed with `set -o octalzeroes`. `zsh` supports a few more notations such as `6#123` to express numbers in different bases, or `0b1001` for binary.

To do it without forking nor relying on external utilities, in `bash`, you could do:

```
printf -v format '\\%o' "${values[@]}"
printf "$format"
```

(for `bash`'s `printf`, `0123` is octal, and number representations such as `1e2`, `0b100`, `2#100` are not supported. `"a` or `'a` however can be used to specify the value of the corresponding character¹).

---

<sup>¹ byte value in locales using single byte character encodings (so `0141` for `a` on ASCII-based systems) or wchar_t value in locales using multi byte character encodings (Unicode code points on GNU systems)</sup>

Comment: thanks for this answer, I see, bash don't have that integration. I have to go with php or perl